# How to bring eggs to room temperature fast while baking?

Tags: baking

Some recipes call for eggs at room temperature. How can I bring the egg to room temperature quickly? I have seen suggestions to place it in hot water for five minutes, will that affect the texture of the egg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Serious Eats](https://www.seriouseats.com/2018/01/how-to-troubleshoot-winter-baking-projects.html) recommends three minutes in a bowl of hot tap water. The article doesn't mention any unfortunate effect on texture - and given that the whole article is based on making the textures of baking projects work, I think it's safe to assume there's no problem.

Comment: I can confirm this.  I use this technique frequently and have never noticed any problematic egg texture.  I will say that separating eggs is more difficult when they are room temperature, so it you need to separate the eggs, I do recommend doing that while they are cold.  You can make a little water bath with hot water around whatever dish you separated the eggs into if you want to warm them up quickly after separating.

Answer (score 1):

I always used to stick the egg in my pocket for a bit.  It's not really in the way if one is just walking around or sitting quietly (ie, at the computer) for that amount of time - it's not that often one gets smacked in the pockets while in one's own kitchen :)

The egg gets warmish pretty fast (minutes) even if that warmish doesn't necessarily equal room temperature, and it's a gentle warmth... very difficult to overheat that way!  One might find bits of lint on the eggshell, but one doesn't eat the shell so I never cared.

It is a haphazard, handwavy result, and it suited me (who is both handwavy and kinda haphazard myself), since it did bring the eggs' temps up pretty quickly and required almost no effort on my part.  If you're looking for speed, precision, or neatness perigon's answer of a bowl of hot water is likely better.  If you just want warmish, quickish and for minimum effort... pockets work :)